# Java: Ordenar ítems según cierto criterio

Tags: java, arraylist

No sé si pueden ayudarme con lo siguiente: tengo un arraylist en el que agrego mediante un `for` **10 empleados**, lo que intento ahora es mostrar por consola **pero agrupado por cargo**, primero todos los médicos, luego enfermeros, etc.

Parte del código es el siguiente, pero cuando pongo el primer `if` me muestra correctamente todos los celadores, a partir del `else if` viene el problema.

```
  if (lista_trabajadores.get(i).getCargo().equalsIgnoreCase("celador")) {
                System.out.println(lista_trabajadores.get(i));

            } else if (lista_trabajadores.get(i).getCargo().equalsIgnoreCase("enfermero")) {

                System.out.println(lista_trabajadores.get(i));
            } else if (lista_trabajadores.get(i).getCargo().equalsIgnoreCase("medico")) {

                System.out.println(lista_trabajadores.get(i));
            } else if (lista_trabajadores.get(i).getCargo().equalsIgnoreCase("cirujano")) {
                System.out.println(lista_trabajadores.get(i));
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que querés decir `ordenados` por cargo, por que agrupado es otra cosa. Eso se logra implementando interfaz `Comparable` o `Comparator`

Comment: Eso es, gracias por la corrección, al momento de imprimir la lista debe ser por cargo.

Comment: En la respuesta te voy a pasar la implementación de la interfaz. También, y es mas sencillo, se puede hacer por base de datos, o sea cuando haces la consulta le decís que te lo ordene. Pero no estas usando base de datos no?

Comment: Podrías indicarme bien el criterio de ordenamiento?

Comment: Sobre su comentario anterior, aun no estoy con base de datos, el criterio de ordenamiento es imprimir la lista por ejemplo, primero todos con el cargo = celador, seguido por enfermero, medico y cirujano.

Comment: Bueno costó un poquito jaja, ya que nunca lo usé de esa forma, comparando String

Answer (score 2):

Implementando interfaz **Comparable** para ordenar objetos con el método **sort** de la interfaz **Collections**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OrdenEmpleado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Empleado> lista_trabajadores =new ArrayList<>();
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(1, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(2, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(3, "Enfermero"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(4, "Enfermero"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(5, "Cirujano"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(6, "Cirujano"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(7, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(8, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(9, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(10, "Cirujano"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(11, "Celador"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(12, "Celador"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(13, "Enfermero"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(14, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(15, "Enfermero"));

        Collections.sort(lista_trabajadores);

        for(Empleado e:lista_trabajadores)
            System.out.println(e);
    }

}
class Empleado implements Comparable<Empleado>{

    private int id;
    private String cargo;

    public Empleado(int id, String cargo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    //sobreescribimos el compareTo ya que estamos implementando interfaz Comparable
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Empleado e) {
        //oren: celador, enfermero, médico, cirujano
        //Resumidamente el compareTo funciona así:
        //Debe retornar alguno de estos valores -1, 1, 0.
        //-1 significa que el this es menor al parámetro e, por lo tanto
        //el Collections.sort al ordenar ejecuta el compareTo y va a interpretar 
        //que el this debe ir primero. En cambio si el compareTo devuelve 1, interpreta que
        //el this es mayor al parámetro e, por lo tanto no va a ir primero. Y por
        //último, si devuelve 0 (cero) interpreta que son iguales entonces por ende
        //no hace falta ordenarlos.
        //Esto cuesta un poco comprender al principio pero vas a ver que haciendo
        //algunos ejercicios todo se aclara
        int resultado =0;
        if(this.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("celador")){
            if(!e.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("celador"))
                resultado =-1;
            else if(e.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("celador"))
                resultado =0;
            else
                resultado =1;
        }
        else if(this.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("enfermero")){
            if(!e.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("enfermero"))
                resultado =-1;
            else if(e.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("enfermero"))
                resultado =0;
            else
                resultado =1;
        }
        else if(this.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("médico")){//(ojo con olvidar tilde)
            if(!e.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("médico"))
                resultado =-1;
            else if(e.cargo.equalsIgnoreCase("médico"))
                resultado =0;
            else
                resultado =1;
        }

        return resultado;    
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: "+ id +", Cargo: "+cargo;
    }

}
```

Nota: el método **compareTo()** no está testeado profundamente, por lo tanto si se encuentra algún error haganmelo saber, como así también si existe alguna forma más sencilla de implementar.

Answer (score 2):

Me sumo al código que subió el amigo Juan Rom, pero con una modificación:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OrdenEmpleado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Empleado> lista_trabajadores =new ArrayList<>();
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(1, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(2, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(3, "Enfermero"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(4, "Enfermero"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(5, "Cirujano"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(6, "Cirujano"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(7, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(8, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(9, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(10, "Cirujano"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(11, "Celador"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(12, "Celador"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(13, "Enfermero"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(14, "Médico"));
        lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(15, "Enfermero"));

        Collections.sort(lista_trabajadores);

        for(Empleado e:lista_trabajadores)
            System.out.println(e);
    }

}
class Empleado implements Comparable<Empleado>{

    private int id;
    private String cargo;

    public Empleado(int id, String cargo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Empleado e) {
        return this.cargo.compareTo(e.cargo);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: "+ id +", Cargo: "+cargo;
    }

}
```

Básicamente lo modifiqué hasta ese punto porque el compareTo necesita devolver un int para manejar el ordenamiento. Entonces, reutilizo el método compareTo que traen los String (así comparo el cargo del empleado actual vs el que viene como argumento) y me los deja ordenados con mucho menos código.

NOTA: Esto sirve porque Christopher no aclaró en qué **orden quieren que se ordene**, sino que le importe que estén **ordenados-agrupados por cargo**. El ordenamiento de Strings, por defecto, se basa en el orden alfabético. De hecho, está salida devolvería algo como:

`ID: 11, Cargo: Celador
ID: 12, Cargo: Celador
ID: 5, Cargo: Cirujano
ID: 6, Cargo: Cirujano
ID: 10, Cargo: Cirujano
ID: 3, Cargo: Enfermero
ID: 4, Cargo: Enfermero
ID: 13, Cargo: Enfermero
ID: 15, Cargo: Enfermero
ID: 1, Cargo: Médico
ID: 2, Cargo: Médico
ID: 7, Cargo: Médico
ID: 8, Cargo: Médico
ID: 9, Cargo: Médico
ID: 14, Cargo: Médico`

Comment: Buen aporte amigo! Cómo me la compliqué jaja. Es cierto, solo funciona cuando el orden de los cargos coincide con el orden alfabético. Muy importante ese último detalle ya que es una gran limitación. Mi código tampoco funciona cuando no coincide con el alfabético. Lo probé con el orden: médico, cirujano, enfermero, celador, y falla, a pesar que no se usa el `compareTo` de `String`, eso debe ser por que el `compareTo` de `Comparable` internamente utiliza el orden alfabético

Answer (score 1):

Quizá tengas la respuesta, pero aquí te presento otra opción

```
package javaapplication4;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
*
* @author Luisa
*/
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Empleado> lista_trabajadores = new ArrayList<>();
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(1, "Médico"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(2, "Médico"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(3, "Enfermero"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(4, "Enfermero"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(5, "Cirujano"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(6, "Cirujano"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(7, "Médico"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(8, "Médico"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(9, "Médico"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(10, "Cirujano"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(11, "Celador"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(12, "Celador"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(13, "Enfermero"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(14, "Médico"));
    lista_trabajadores.add(new Empleado(15, "Enfermero"));

    Map<String, List<Empleado>> map = lista_trabajadores.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.getCargo()));
    map.values().forEach((entry) -> {
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    });

}

public static class Empleado {

    private int id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empleado{" + "id=" + id + ", cargo=" + cargo + '}';
    }
    private String cargo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public Empleado(int id, String cargo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }
}

}
```

Puedes utilizar el metodo groupingBy de [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

La idea es meter todo a un Map donde el key sera el cargo, y cada cargo tendrá una lista de List quedando algo así:

[image: Ejemplo de Map]

Luego bastará recorrer el map para mostrar los valores.

**Actualización**

A petición del OP se agregan dos formas de ordenar alfabéticamente

Se usa **Map.Entry.comparingByKey()**

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(e.toString()));
```

Además se puede usar **TreeMap**

```
    Map<String, List<Empleado>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(map);
      treeMap.values().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    });
```

Comment: Luisa descubrimos que tanto mi solución como la de @NahuelGiani son limitadas en el sentido que el orden de los cargos debe coincidir con el orden alfabético, que es justamente el caso de la pregunta, en cambio si quisiéramos por ej. este orden: médico, cirujano, enfermero, celador, ya no funciona. Por lo tanto tu solución sería la mejor solo en el caso de poder dar un orden deseado, por que si bien lo agrupa perfectamente, lo presenta en el orden: cirujano, celador, médico, enfermero. Cómo se puede pedir otro orden

Comment: De todas formas aclaro que yo me quedo con tu solución, ya que es más importante el agrupado, pero sería bárbaro si también se puede ordenar los grupos

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, puedes echarle un ojo. @JuanRom

Comment: Yo decía si se podrá ordenar los grupos en un orden distinto al alfabético, como ser : médico, cirujano, enfermero, celador

Comment: Pero en base a que criterio piensas ordenarlo? Quizá eso no logro comprender @JuanRom Para ordenarlo se tiene que decir en base a que criterio, puede ser ascendente, descendente, alfabético, etc.O si sé ocupan dos campos para ordenar.